# Numerical resolution of Schrödinger 1D Time Independent Equation, why do Energies not following the expected pattern?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, computational-physics

I want to solve numerically the 1D time independent Schrödinger:

$$-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m} \dfrac{d^2 \psi(x)}{dx^2} + V(x)\psi(x) = E\psi(x)$$

For starter, lets say we solve the [Particle In a Box](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Mechanics/05.5%3A_Particle_in_Boxes/Particle_in_a_1-Dimensional_box) problem with the following boundary conditions:

$$V(x) = 0, \psi(-L/2) = \psi(L/2) = 0, \psi'(-L/2) = 1$$

Where Energy $E$ is a free parameter.

I have written the following Python/SciPy code to do so:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hbar = 1
m = 1
L = 1

def U(x):
    """Potential"""
    return np.zeros_like(x)

def model(x, psi, p):
    """Time Independent Schrödinger Equation"""
    E = p[0]
    return np.array([
        psi[1],
        (2. * m / np.power(hbar, 2)) * (U(x) - E) * psi[0],
    ])

def bc(ya, yb, p):
    """Boundary Conditions"""
    return np.array([
        ya[0],
        yb[0],
        ya[1] - 1,
    ])

# Grid:
xlin = np.linspace(- L / 2., + L / 2., 2001)
y0 = np.ones((2, xlin.size))

# Initial Guess for Energy: 
#E0s = [(i + 1)**2 * hbar**2 * np.pi**2 / (2 * m * L**2) for i in range(5)]  # Gives strange results
E0s = [(2*i + 1)**2 * hbar**2 * np.pi**2 / (2 * m * L**2) for i in range(5)]

# Solutions:
sols = []
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
for E0 in E0s:
    sol = integrate.solve_bvp(model, bc, xlin, y0, p=[E0], max_nodes=10000)
    sols.append(sol.p[0])
    axe.plot(xlin, sol.sol(xlin)[0], label="E = %.3g" % sol.p[0])
axe.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
axe.set_title("Schrödinger Equation Solutions")
axe.set_xlabel("Space, $x$ [m]")
axe.set_ylabel("Wave function, $\psi(x)$")
axe.grid()
```

Which returns the following non normalized solutions and associated energies:

[image]

They looks like sinusoidal curves as expected.

The solver and initial guess quite agree:

[image]

But I was expecting Energy pattern to be:

$$E_n = \dfrac{(n + 1)^{2}h^{2}}{8mL^{2}}$$

Instead of (found by trial error):

$$E_n = \dfrac{(2n + 1)^{2}h^{2}}{8mL^{2}}$$

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems like you have no solution that has an odd symmetry. Since all your solutions have even symmetry, it is no wonder that it fits only half the possible eigenenergies.

Comment: Minor nitpick: since python `range` starts at 0, you're actually computing $n^2$ in the first case and picking odd squares in the second (which makes sense since you have only cosine functions displayed).

Comment: @KyleKanos, that's the point of my question, when I use $n^2$ I don't get even symmetry.

Comment: You should be getting odd symmetry...

Answer (score 1):

Since the particle is free inside the well, the solutions of Schrödinger equation are of the form $\psi_k(x)=A\cos kx$ or $A\sin kx$. The wave function should vanish at the two walls
$$\psi(-L/2)=\psi(L/2)=0$$
I do not understand why you impose $\psi'(-L/2)=0$ but Ok... The cosine function vanishes at $\pm {\pi\over 2}, \pm {3\pi\over 2}, {5\pi\over 2},\ldots {(2n+1)\pi\over 2}$ with $n\in \mathbb N^*$. As a consequence, the condition at the boundary
$$k{L\over 2}={(2n+1)\pi\over 2}\ \Leftrightarrow\ k={(2n+1)\pi\over L}$$
leading to the quantization of the wavevector and of the energy
$$E_k={\hbar^2\over 2m}={h^2(2n+1)^2\over 8mL^2}$$
**Conclusion**: your code is correct but not your theoretically expected eigenenergies!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, one of the first things to check in computational physics is whether you have discretized your domain to a sufficiently fine mesh. If you check the status or message variables for the solutions which exhibit odd behavior, you will find that they did not converge properly. Try adding a zero to the number of points in your $x$ grid.

Comment: With `n=2001` and `max_nodes=10000` I have got the following message `The algorithm converged to the desired accuracy` which seems OK to me.

Comment: @jlandercy Are you checking one of your "odd behavior" solutions? Your solutions with odd integers are fine.

Comment: Increased `max_nodes=50000`, with `E0s = [(i)**2 * h**2 / (8 * m * L**2) for i in range(10)]`, fit are OK but solutions are still only those I pick up with `(2*i + 1)**2`.